# Fastest way to join two indexes into a third

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following two es indexes:

```
index1 = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "fred",
    "shared_id": 77
}    

index2 = {
    "id": 89,
    "FacebookID": 9288347,
    "shared_id": 77
}
```

I want to merge these two indexes into a third index:

```
index3 = {
    "index1.id": 1,
    "index2.id": 89,
    "shared_id": 77,
    "FacebookID": 9288347,
}
```

In other words, all objects with a sharedID will be merged into a third object with all existing attributes. What would be the performant way to do this? My current idea is to download all the data in the two objects and use either Java or C++ to do the merge/upload. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps something native to ES itself? I would estimate several million objects per index.

I've found this, which suggests the best solution is to search both indexes simultaneously or manually join them: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Merging-Two-Indexes-td4021708.html.

Comment: Are the first two documents indexed at the same time in ES or are they indexed at different time by different processes?

Comment: Have you considered having a filtered alias pointing to multiple indices?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered

Comment: Nothing like this out-of-the-box in ES. Consider searching both of them at the same time, if it applies and, as @Devi suggested take a look at aliases. Why do you want them merged, in the first place?